# Dual license GPL/non-commercial + commercial SDK license

Tags: gpl, commercial, copyleft, dual-license

Looking to release an open-source SDK, all of which uses novel code OR dependencies that are MIT/Apache.

For the business model, I would like to sell commercial-use licenses for use with the SDK, allowing people to use the library in their for-profit applications. Simultaneously, I would like there to be a free non-commercial use copyleft license (i.e., GPL) that allows people to build free, open-source software using the SDK.

What is a proper license that will work for this arrangement? Looking specifically for a commercial SDK license, since GPL is easy to find.

Comment: Could you clarify what your SDK consists of (e.g. a library, tools, both). For example, if you create an SDK which has (say) a compiler and release that under the GPL, there's nothing in the GPL that will disallow a company from using that software to make their own non-GPL covered programs using those tools. However, if the SDK includes a GPL library, then a company including that library in their software would be obligated to release source code, too (under the GPL), unless that company purchases an alternative (i.e. non-GPL) license for that library.

Comment: "free non-commercial use copyleft license (i.e., GPL)" <- you have a misunderstanding of the GPL; it explicitly allows commercial use.

Comment: The SDK consists of just source code. No DLLs, precompile libraries, executables, compilers, etc. The source code has NO GPL dependencies, only MIT/apache.

Comment: I know very little of licenses, so if I show misunderstanding, and you think you know a better model for what I need, I'm all ears

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you are asking for a closed-source license recommendation. That is off-topic for this site and you are advised to consult a lawyer for that part. We can only help in the open-source part.

Comment: Thomas: per the above, the GPL is NOT non-commercial (nor is any OSS license).  And you haven't answered Brandin's question about what's in the SDK.  Without clarification, your question isn't answerable.

Comment: "The SDK consists of just source code. No DLLs, precompile libraries, executables, compilers, etc. The source code has NO GPL dependencies, only MIT/apache." Specifically, source code to build p2p networking apps